# Saiku File not showing in Ivy Dashboard Designer Pentaho BI Server CE

Tags: pentaho, saiku, dashboard-designer

Hi I am using pentaho Bi Server community edition.
I created a Saiku Analytics File (say demo.saiku) and saved it in /home/admin folder.
After that i created a new Ivy Dashboard, Drag and dropped an Analytics Menu in a dashboard Window.
Set the title and layout properties.
Now when i click on Datasource Properties it asks me to choose a saiku file through a drop-down list but there is no file listed in it.

how to use my saved saiku analytics report in Ivy dashboard designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer:

I have to save the saiku analytics report in public folders instead of admin folders. After i did that, the reports showed up in ivy dashboard designer